# Update ng-init in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML**

```
 <div class="right" data-ng-attr-id=i value="{% verbatim %}{{indexValue}}{% endverbatim %}">
    <img ng-src="{% verbatim %}{{link[indexValue].uploaded_id}}{% endverbatim %}" data-ng-attr-test={{test}} class="img" value="{% verbatim %}{{link[indexValue].uploaded_id}}{% endverbatim %}"
        ng-model="test" ng-init='test= getId()' ng-show="test" /> {% verbatim %}{{analysis_obj.wptId}}{% endverbatim %}
    <div class="bottom-progress">
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="progress_style('{{ django_upload_id }}'+{% verbatim %}{{ analysis_obj.wptId }}{% endverbatim %})"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
for (var i = 1; i <= wptListLength * 5; i++) {
    $scope['img' + i] = true;
    console.log("Gen Values" + $scope['img' + i]);
}

var current = 1;
$scope.getId = function () {

        var j = current;
        console.log("Current in controller for " + 'img' + j + " " + $scope['img' + j]);
        current = current + 1;
        if (current == (wptListLength * 5 + 1)) {
            current = 1;
            j = 1;
        }
return $scope['img'+j];
}
```

Later during a operation I update the `$scope['img'+j]` , how to make it get reflected in `ng-show` and `ng-model`. First set value of `ng-init="test=getId()"` In case if I want to do a watch. How to watch a large set of values dynamically created.